# One action or multiple method calls from multiple actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

With a method that is going to be call by many buttons, what is better, to call this method in each button’s action or create an action that all the buttons call in order to perform this method?

Thanks.

Comment: I think one method is better. You can distinguish the buttons by setting a tag and then checking it in method call.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is for general use, for example I have a method by that I am calling "Call" function to make call. I would write that method in appDalegate. Because this method performs the same action by various button click. like:

in delegate.m

```
- (void) makeCall:(NSString *)number
{
   NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",number]];
   NSLog(@"%@ from delegate",phoneNumberURL);
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
}
```

And If your method needs to differentiate button's click , say by `tag`, then I would like to write separate methods rather having `if....else if...` or `switch`.

Hope it gives you an idea..

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is much better as it allows you keeps you code organised and you can always determine which button has called the method by using the `[sender tag]` or comparing the sender itself in a `switch` or `if` loop respectively.